# Print each word of a sentence in a new line

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, f#

this is my first `F#` program, very simple concept but took me a few minutes to get it. I'm new to functional programming so I'd appreciate if you could have a look at and comment the code.

Suggest changes or any code smells?

```
module FSharpFun.PrintSentenceInLines

open System

let printWord w = printfn "%s" w
let printEveryWord = Array.map printWord
let splitIntoWords (s:String) = s.Split ()

// Read a line and print each word in a new line
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    Console.ReadLine () |> splitIntoWords |> printEveryWord |> ignore
    0
```

Comment: `Array.iter` instead of `Array.map` is a more appropriate here. Then we can eventually get rid of the last `|> ignore`. Finally and less important, we could inline `printEveryWord` because `Array.iter printWord` reads well enough.

Comment: Just made the changes, it looks much better, I will read up a bit to understand why I didn't need the last `|>` ignore.
Now that I've made the change this program looks even more basic, but that's ok. Baby steps :) Thanks a lot

Comment: When you use `Array.map` the result is another array, of `Unit`s, one per each word you printed.
That array needs to be `ignore`-ed since it's a value and the F# compiler likes its values to be "attached" to something.

Opting for `Array.iter` gives you a single `Unit` as output, and `Unit` is a sort of "no data value", so the compiler ignores it on its own.
(This is, of course, very figurative, but it's "correct enough" to explain why `iter` is better, more correct even).

And, as Romain said, just go with `... |> Array.iter (fun w -> printfn $"%s{w}")`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the code itself reads just as simply as a name for a function, so you could inline all of this and reduce the urge for the reader to jump up to a function definition to check what exactly a function is doing:

```
splitIntoWords
```

vs

```
fun s -> s.Split()
```

And then:

```
printEveryWord
```

vs

```
Array.iter (printfn "%s")
```

In this case, I'd want to check the function just to understand there wasn't magic around what exactly a 'word' is. If the code is inlined, I can see it's just based on string splitting.

```fs
let main _ =
    Console.ReadLine()
    |> fun s -> s.Split()
    |> Array.iter (printfn "%s")
```

`printfn "%s"` is itself a function which expects a string

```
> printfn "%s";;
val it : (string -> unit) = <fun:it@1>
```

So it works great as is to pass into `Array.iter`

Comment: I really like this solution, thank you!